# PHP encoding with unicode

Tags: php, unicode, encoding

How can I get an HTML entity out of a thing like `\u00e4`, which stands for `&aauml;` (ä)?

I have backslashes in the string, for escape reason. When I strip slashes I get something like `u00e4`. I have to strips lashes to be able to store and restore it to the session.

Comment: You've edited the original question to add a mention to `stripslashes`. A backslash (\\) has nothing to do with neither HTML nor Unicode so it's time you explain your exact problem and maybe post some code.

Comment: the main problem is : how can i get an htmlentity out of a thing like that: \00e4, which stands for &auml; (ä). it does NOT work with htmlentities!!

Comment: slashes are escaped with a backslash, as we all know. when i strip slashes i loose my unicode "character", therefor i need to escape the unicode (the slashes issue is just to argue why i need to decode that unicode)

Comment: I have already told you in my comment what your problem is. \00e4 is NOT an escape sequence for ä.  \0 denotes an octal notation, which \00e4 is not. You need to use \xE4 or \344

Comment: this is what i get form json, so what is it than? omg, json ...

Comment: The binary representation of ä in HEX is 0xE4. PHP can convert special sequences from hax-notation to it's binary representation. Like this: \xE4, there is another representation called octal (number system with the base 8): \344 = 3*8^2 + 4*8^1 + 4*8^0 = 288
See here:
http://ch.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: Can't you just post the code so we can see what is actually going on? That way we can go from guessing to solving the actual problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As you can see in the discussions, and answeres, it is a problem, which php can't handle native (or until now nobody here knows)

i suggest using this very havy function ... i mean, this is my solution so far, which i do  not like, very much.

```
function parse_umlaut($string){

        $string = str_replace('u00c4', 'Ä', $string);
        $string = str_replace('u00e4', 'ä', $string);
        $string = str_replace('u00d6', 'Ö', $string);
        $string = str_replace('u00f6', 'ö', $string);
        $string = str_replace('u00dc', 'Ü', $string);
        $string = str_replace('u00fc', 'ü', $string);
        $string = str_replace('u00df', 'ß', $string);

        return $string;
 }
```

Comment: I thought it was a humorous answer... There are more than 100,000 Unicode code points--are you planning to replace them all one by one or just add new lines as your code crashes with new user input? Not to mention that it has a typo (it omits the backslash) and it fixes the wrong problem.

Comment: why can't you just post the code that provides you with which you get these umlaut strings? If we could look at that, maybe we could help you fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

With [htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities):

```
<?php

echo htmlentities("\xE4");

?>
```

However, it's worth noting that:

1. Sessions do not care about character encoding.
2. HTML entities are not required in HTML Unicode documents (except for chars with a special meaning in HTML such as `<` and `>`).

So this won't fix your problem, it will just hide it ;-)

## Update

I had overlooked the reference to `\00e4` in the original question. The **ä** character corresponds to the `U+00E4` Unicode code point. However, PHP does not support Unicode code points. If you need to **type** it in your PHP **code** and your keyboard does not have such symbol, you can save the document as UTF-8 and then provide the UTF-8 bytes (c3 a4) with the [double quote syntax](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double):

```
<?php
// \[0-7]{1,3} or \x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}
echo "\xc3\xa4";
?>
```

Still, this has no relation to sessions or HTML. I can't understand what your exact problem is.

## Second update

So serialize() cannot handle associative arrays and json_decode() cannot be fed with json_encode()'s output...

```
<?php

$associative_array = array(
    'foo' => 'ä',
    'bar' => 33,
    'gee' => array(10, 20, 30),
);

var_dump($associative_array);
echo PHP_EOL;
var_dump(serialize($associative_array));
echo PHP_EOL;
var_dump(unserialize(serialize($associative_array)));
echo PHP_EOL;

var_dump(json_encode($associative_array));
echo PHP_EOL;
var_dump(json_decode(json_encode($associative_array)));
echo PHP_EOL;

?>
```

...

```
array(3) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(2) "ä"
  ["bar"]=>
  int(33)
  ["gee"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(10)
    [1]=>
    int(20)
    [2]=>
    int(30)
  }
}

string(83) "a:3:{s:3:"foo";s:2:"ä";s:3:"bar";i:33;s:3:"gee";a:3:{i:0;i:10;i:1;i:20;i:2;i:30;}}"

array(3) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(2) "ä"
  ["bar"]=>
  int(33)
  ["gee"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(10)
    [1]=>
    int(20)
    [2]=>
    int(30)
  }
}

string(42) "{"foo":"\u00e4","bar":33,"gee":[10,20,30]}"

object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(2) "ä"
  ["bar"]=>
  int(33)
  ["gee"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(10)
    [1]=>
    int(20)
    [2]=>
    int(30)
  }
}
```

It appears to me that you are adding several layers of complexity to a simple script because you are making assumptions about how some PHP functions work instead of checking the manual or testing yourself. At this point, the information provided hardly resembles the original question and we still haven't seen a single line of code.

My advice so far is that you try to stop debugging your app as a whole, divide it into smaller pieces and use var_dump() to find out what each of these parts actually generate. Don't assume things: test stuff yourself. Also, take into account that PHP doesn't Unicode natively as others languages do. Every single task that involves double-byte string handling must be carefully implemented with the appropriate multi-byte functions, which often require to hard-code the character encoding.

Comment: so where do u get an entity of \00e4 ? i don't want to parse to much, if i parse \00e4 to \xE4 i can also parse it to &auml; ...

Comment: Actually, `\00e4` means nothing in PHP. It's not a valid octal number because it contains an `e`. How do you get such string in the first place?

Comment: it comes from json_encode function
i thaught it is unicode. so what is this? any ideas? thanks

Comment: It's json's way of denoting Unicode characters. In that case, you should be able to use json_decode.

Comment: If you use json_encode() you should be getting `\u00e4`, not `\00e4`. Unlike PHP, JavaScript does support Unicode code points. If you want the original string back, just use json_decode()!

Comment: json_decode will work for decoding a string, but doesn't work in for my case, because i json_encode an associative array, to be able to store it to the session (fyi serialize didn't work the way i needed it in this special case!). i don't want to walk through every value, because the array is huge and nested.

Answer (score 1):

How do you mean you have problems reloading it?
Do you output it to a HTML page? In that case, you might have set the wrong charset.
As for using entities, check this out:
[htmlentitites](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a perfectly reasonable answer given the question.

Comment: then what is the problem?
As Álvaro already said, $_SESSION does not care about encodings.

Concerning your edit: If stripslashes removes the slash, it means that the string \00e4 was interpreted literally. You seem to be using the octal notation. See Alvaro's post on how to do it with Hex.

Comment: downvote, because it does not solves the problem (the question has nothing to do with html output), but had an upvote. if somebody else has the same problem, he would think this is a good answer, and it's not! sorry, don't take it personally ;-)

Comment: for your original question, it was a perfectly reasonable answer. Excuse me that I do not possess the power foresight to discover your actual problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this one helps you but take a look at Wordpress' [sanitize_title](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/formatting.php) function where you can find some huge character tables.

Comment: You don't need to use WordPress. Use some code from linked source if it helps.